# How can i remove the colon ":" from Woocommerce variation label?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Trying to remove the colon ":" from woocommerce single product page.
[see attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4eUC.jpg)

Not sure what to input for the attribute label code.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_attribute_label', 'custom_attribute_label')

Appreciate any help on this please.

Answer (score 1):

This should be your solution. You'll have to add this, to the functions.php file of a child theme, to a custom WordPress plugin that you create or use a snippets plugin, although I recommend you don't do that last option. Not ideal for performance nor for security.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_attribute_label', 'barrytea_attribute_label');

function barrytea_attribute_label( $label, $name, $product ){
    
    $filtered_label = str_replace( ':', '', $label);
    return $filtered_label;
}
```